# Angular 13 http call to API give Error trying to diff 'Test Auction Name One'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.Net Core Web API project that is getting called by an Angular 13 project. I thought everything would be working just fine because I can `console.log` the data being sent from the API. As soon as I tried to display the data in the HTML component with a `*ngFor` loop I get the following error. As you can see the `console.log` is showing the correct data. I've search the internet and all the recommended post here on SO but nothing has seem to work. any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Here is the Interface

```
export interface Auction {
  auctionId: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  longDescription: string;
  bidIncrement: number;
  bidAmount: number;
}
```

Service call

```
//SERVICE 
getAPI(): Observable<Auction[]> { 
 return this.http.get<Auction[]>('https://localhost:5001/api/auction')
.pipe(
  map((data: Auction[]) => this.auctionList = data), 
  tap(data => console.log('All', JSON.stringify(data))), 
  catchError(this.handleError)
  );    
}
```

Component section

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

errorMessage = ''; 

 auctionList: Auction[] = [];       

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {      
    this.getAuctionList(); 
 }

  getAuctionList() { 
   return this.getAPI().subscribe({
   next: response => { 
    this.auctionList = response;                                     
   },
   error: err => this.errorMessage  = err      
  }); 
 }
}
```

HTML Component

```
Auction List: 
 <ul >
   <li *ngFor="let item of auctionList" >
    {{ item.auctionId }}        
  </li>  
 </ul>
```

Comment: Can you explain what ```map((data: Auction[]) => this.auctionList = data)``` does? Why do you assign to this.auctionList twice?

Comment: From my understanding, I'm mapping the `this.auctionList` to the `data` type of `Auction[]` (Array). the `((data: Auction[]))` is casting the `data` as type Array. If that makes sense.

Comment: Typescript does not ‘cast’. Your data is an object, not an array. You can use the keyvalue pipe in your template to use *ngFor with an object.